# can a dockerised app execute script on the host?

Tags: docker

If I have an application running in a docker container, is it possible to have it execute a shell script on the host? I'm pretty sure there is no way to achieve this - on purpose, such is the nature of containers - but want to check. Thanks.

EDIT: and failing that, is there a way for the app to interact with the docker engine running on the host so that it can trigger a "docker stop" "docker run.." etc for other containers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There might be a [different approach](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

Well, technically, it does. Processes are run on the host even when from inside a container. You can verify this when running `ps aux` as root on the host : you'll see the dockerized processes.

The question is : what interaction is your script supposed to have with the system ? If it's taking files as input, accessing databases or network resource, then all of this is possible for a dockerized script. You'll just have to define volumes and links.

About the docker engine : yes it is also possible for a container to control its own docker engine. You just have to add this to the docker command :

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

That way, a docker client (inside the container) will have access to the docker engine (via docker API).